# Divide a line in n equal parts

Tags: swift, uiview, geometry, draw

I am drawing a line from point A(x1,y1) to point B(x2,y2). Now I need to divide this line in n equal parts. Line is not straight so I am not able to calculate the points on the basis of x axis and width.
I am drawing the line as following:

```
let lineTop = DrawFiguresViewModel.getLine(fromPoint: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y), toPoint: CGPoint(x: (point.x-100), y: (point.y-100)))
self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineTop)

class DrawFiguresViewModel{
    class func getLine(fromPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint) -> CALayer{
        let line = CAShapeLayer()
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: start)
        linePath.addLine(to: end)
        line.path = linePath.cgPath
        line.strokeColor = Colors.lineColor.cgColor
        line.lineWidth = 2
        line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        return line
    }
}
```

Any head start in this direction will be great.

**Edit1:**
I want to draw diagram like [image: this].

I am able to draw the bold lines but now I need to draw fine line with text cause and why. There can be multiple causes at equal distance on the vertical(slanted) line.

**Edit2:**
After adding code from Martin, I get it as [image: this]
Although it is good but it is slightly offset. Also as it is n+1 I am removing 0 index value before drawing it.

**Edit3:**
Following is the code for drawing the lines using Martin's function:

```
if(node.childs.count > 0){
            var arrPoints = divideSegment(start: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y), end: CGPoint(x: (point.x-100), y: (point.y-100)), parts: node.childs.count)
            arrPoints.remove(at: 0)
            print(arrPoints)
            for (index,obj) in node.childs.enumerated(){
                if let nodeN = obj as? DataNode{
                    let pointN = arrPoints[index]
                    drawLevel1Line(point: pointN, nodeTitle: nodeN.title)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry but this question is unclear. Please [edit] your question to make it clear. Include a specific example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Divide both x- and y-interval into n equal parts, and create points from the x/y pairs.

Comment: actually this is what I want to do but don't know how to do

Comment: @rmaddy please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with the initial point, and then repeatedly increment both x- and y-coordinate by a fixed amount which is computed such that after
n steps the endpoint of the segment is reached (in other words: linear interpolation):

```
/// Returns an array of (`n` + 1) equidistant points from `start` to `end`.
func divideSegment(from start: CGPoint, to end: CGPoint, parts n: Int) -> [CGPoint] {
    let ΔX = (end.x - start.x) / CGFloat(n)
    let ΔY = (end.y - start.y) / CGFloat(n)
    return (0...n).map {
        CGPoint(x: start.x + ΔX * CGFloat($0),
                y: start.y + ΔY * CGFloat($0)) 
    }
}
```

Example:

```
print(divideSegment(from: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1), to: CGPoint(x: 4, y: 5), parts: 4))
// [(1.0, 1.0), (1.75, 2.0), (2.5, 3.0), (3.25, 4.0), (4.0, 5.0)]
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the answer, please check my edit, it is slight offset. I have used your code.

Comment: @pankaj: Sorry, I don't see why it is not working for you. As you can see in my example, the first point in the array is the given initial point, the last point in the array is the given endpoint, and all points have the same distance.

Comment: Your code is perfect. After doing some research I found it was bit offset in my drawing code.